# python convert string "0" to float gives error

Tags: python, string

i have the following code in my python script, to launch an application and grab the output of it.

An example of this output would be 'confirmed : 0'

Now i only want to know the number, in this case zero, but normally this number is float, like 0.005464

When i run this code it tells me it cannot convert "0" to float. What am i doing wrong?

This is the error i get now:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "0"

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen('/Applications/Electrum.app/Contents/MacOS/Electrum getbalance', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in cmd.stdout:
    if "confirmed" in line:
    a,b=line.split(': ',1)
    if float(b)>0:
        print "Positive amount"
    else:
        print "Empty"
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste the traceback exactly?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "maken.py", line 81, in <module>
    check=float(b)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "0"

Comment: do `print repr(line)` after `for` and paste it

Answer (score 5):

According to the exception you got, the value contained in `b` is not `0`, but `"0"` (including the quotes), and therefore cannot be converted to a float directly. You'll need to remove the quotes first, e.g. with `float(b.strip('"'))`.

As can be seen in the following examples, the exception description does not add the quotes, so they must have been part of the original string:

```
>>> float('"0"')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "0"
>>> float('a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: a
```

Comment: just tried, but it only removes 1 quote it seems: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "maken.py", line 81, in <module>
    if float(b.strip('"'))>0:
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0"

Comment: @user2133342 -- That strips leading and trailing `"`.  If there are spaces, before or after the `"`, that would do it.  You could try:  `if float(b.strip(' "\n'))`.  On second thought, your line probably ends with a trailing newline, so you'll need to strip those as well.  At this point, it may be easier to just replace the quotes:  `float(b.replace('"',''))`

Comment: @user2133342: Maybe you have some spaces at the end, try `b.strip().strip('"').`. Printing `repr(line)` as Jakub suggests will show you exactly what the string contains.

Comment: Thanks, the b.strip().strip('"') works. what exactly does it do now with the double strip? and why was 1 strip not sufficient?

Comment: @user2133342: [`strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) removes leading/trailing whitespace. `strip('"')` removes leading/trailing quotes. You can also remove both in one call with something like `strip(' \t\n"')`.

Answer (score -1):

I have tested the code and found that split(': ', 1) result contains string

```
>>> line = "1: 456: confirmed"
>>> "confirmed" in line
True
>>> a,b=line.split(': ', 1)
>>> a
'1'
>>> b
'456: confirmed'
```

Comment: The line you tested this on contains multiple `: `, the one OP has contains only one.